# How do I prevent an app from force closing due to low memory

Tags: root-access, insufficient-memory, system-apps

I have a floating application (a paint pad) which "floats as a window" in the foreground, while other apps are running.

However, when I open some large applications, it is force closed.

What I tried?

- Rooted my os
- I made it a system app
- I added an exception to a memory cleaner (that comes default with miui)

Still it force closes.

> How do I reserve some memory to it so that it wouldn't force close automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Open the apk as a zip file and view the AndroidManifest.xml ... Find the line

```
package="com.paint.app"
```

What is your package name ?

Once you have the package name....

1. Open System Folder
2. Open Build.prop as a text document
3. Add the following code, With 1 blank line at the bottom of the manifest - Important to add the blank line ! otherwise you'll boot loop !

   `sys.keep_app_1=com.paint.app`

You can also add more apps to keep in memory by adding another line

```
sys.keep_app_2=com.painter.app
```